# Handling multiples tab's with Python Playwright

Tags: python, web-scraping, playwright

I've read several topics in playwright documentation, but I haven't figured out how i can handle a new tab during the data scrap.I already know how to create a new tab and manipulate it, but for this I pass a url to create this tab, and the scrap I'm doing is like a button that whenever I click takes me to a different site in a new tab, then wanted to know how I can do to move to handle this new tab that opened instead d continue in the old one.

```
for itemId in range(250):
    itemId+=1
    # conferindo se os itens percorridos existem, se sim procede, se não cancela a ação
    if page.locator(("text='{}'".format('%03d' % itemId))):
        page.click("text='{}'".format('%03d' % itemId))
        page.wait_for_timeout(5000)
        page.locator('a[target="_blank"]').click() #parte onde eu queria que passasse a usar a nova guia que abriu ao clicar no botao
        print(page.locator("div[ng-repeat='(colRenderIndex, col) in colContainer.renderedColumns track by col.uid']".format(itemId)).all_text_contents())
        page.wait_for_timeout(5000)
    else:
        break
```

I expect the code manipulating the new tab..

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
# Needed libs
from playwright.sync_api import Playwright, sync_playwright, expect

with sync_playwright() as p:
    #We define the browser, the context and the page
    browser = p.chromium.launch(headless=False)
    context = browser.new_context()
    page = context.new_page()
    # Go to URL for this example
    page.goto("https://demoqa.com/browser-windows")

    # With the current context we wait for a new page, and we do whatever we have to do inside for opening that new page (tab)
    with context.expect_page() as new_page_info:
        # Needed actions for opening the new tab, in my case clicling a button
        page.locator('#tabButton').click()  # Opens a new tab
    # Now we have the new page
    new_page = new_page_info.value
    # We do whatever we want with our new page, in my case it is only taking a text from an element and printing it out
    text_of_h1_from_new_page = new_page.locator('#sampleHeading').inner_text()
    print(text_of_h1_from_new_page)
    # Close the context and browser
    context.close()
    browser.close()
```

More info here: https://playwright.dev/python/docs/pages#handling-new-pages